# Polyglossia and hyperref interference when using french language

Tags: xetex, hyperref, texlive, polyglossia, texlive-2020

I have a warning when compiling the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}    
a
\end{document}
```

Warning is:

```
Failed to patch part for French
```

Configuration : xetex on TL2020 vanilla (polyglossia 1.51, hyperref 7.00e)

It disappears as soon as I disable either hyperref or setdefaultlanguage.
It is still there, no matter how I change the order of the usepackage lines.

I also tried the [frenchpart=false] option for polyglossia as available starting version 1.51, but it does not compile and gives that error :

```
Package keyvalue Error: Unknown option 'frenchpart' for package polyglossia. \ProcessKeysOptions{polyglossia}
```

Any idea why I am getting this?

Regards,
Ivan

Comment: well hyperref changes part (to insert an anchor) and polyglossia doesn't handle this case when trying to patch \part. Report it to polyglossia.

Comment: For reference, it is reported [here](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/469). Thank you Ulrike.